# Delegates in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is it the normal practice in objective c to use the controller as the delegate for various protocol implementations. I'm speaking about when using the iOS SDK, or is it a good idea to have separate classes which take over the roll of a delegate? Or is it simply a case of whatever fits best to the scenario? I largely curious as to best practices in Objective c as I am learning to code it in isolation and have no "real world" expert to turn to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Controller" focuses on ownership and Facade. Outside objects will talk to the controller rather than the controlled. The only object that should generally talk directly to a `UITableView` is the `UITableViewController`. The controller generally owns the controlled object and the controller should have at least as long a lifespan as the controlled.

"Delegate" focuses on behavior, Strategy and Observer. An object asks its delegate for guidance on behaviors (should I show this data? What color should this be? Can I do this action?). An object tells its delegate when interesting things happen (I was touched. I'm about to finish something. I had a problem.) A special kind of delegate answers questions of data (what data goes on line 3?). Those are called datasources.

Where it is common for the rest of the system to talk to a "controller," it is generally not appropriate to talk to a "delegate." So for instance, it is generally appropriate to have a pointer to a `UITableViewController` and send it messages from other places in the system. It is not appropriate to have a pointer to the controller's `tableView`; you should be working through the controller. On the other hand, if you have a pointer to an object, it's generally not appropriate to ask for its `delegate`. If you need to, you've probably designed something incorrectly. (The most noteworthy example is `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` which is almost always the wrong thing to be talking to. AppDelegate is the delegate of the application, not a dumping ground for globals.)

If an object has a controller, the controller almost invariably is the delegate. To my above rules for which you talk to, when an object is both controller and delegate, then it's a controller.

It is possible for a single object to be the delegate of several things, particularly if most of the things are short lived (alert views for instance). It's not unusual for `UIViewController` to be delegate to a few things.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Keeping the delegates as separate classes makes the code clean and portable too. You can reuse those delegate classes for some other purpose just by copying and pasting them and making minor changes.
> 2. There is an advantage of keeping the delegates in the same class over keeping them in separate classes. You can easily access the private variables/objects in the class, which is not possible in the first case.
> 3. If you keep the delegates separate and want to pass some value to the main class, you may have to create another delegate :-) or add observers or you have to pass them using some properties.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Yes, it's very common for a view controller to be the delegate of a view (or more than one view) that it manages.

**Examples:** UITableViewController is a class designed for managing a UITableView instance, and it implements both the table view delegate and table view data source protocols (a data source is just another kind of delegate). Likewise, it'd be natural for a view controller to be the delegate for a picker view, search bar, text field, etc.

**Rationale:** Views really aren't supposed to know about where the data they display comes from, but view controllers do, so it's natural for them to provide data and make decisions about how a given view should behave. The same can be true for other kinds of objects, but you have to use some common sense. The application has its own delegate object that's usually responsible for creating at least some of the view controllers and often the data model, so it obviously wouldn't make sense for that role to be played by a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is depend on requirement as well as in terms of code. Most used best practice is MVC Pattern. You will get the idea once you will implement it. There are also some design patterns you can read. But for iPhone I prefer MVC. And for the delegates yes it is the normal practice in objective-c to use the controller as the delegate. The objective-c is designed in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to broadcast information to several parts of your application, NSNotification is a good choice (even if it may make things a little bit complicated to understand by others).

In other cases, having a delegate associated with a protocol is a good choice to make things clear and isolated in term of code.

KVC is also another way to implement interactions in your code : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html

Depending on what you plan to do, one solution could be better than one other, the best is to play with every solution to learn more about them ... It will help you to take the right decision when you'll design your next iOS application !

Answer (score 0):

Here i go:

Suppose you have a class A and another B.

"a" is the object of class A

In "a" if you instantiate B, as "b" and pass to it  self ie "a"

Now you can easy trigger the method of that variable "a" u just passed to "b" because you have the access to that object. But the havoc starts when you are done with class B and start to release "b". Now because of using "a", all the memory allocated for "b" will be released but nor freed and will be entangled as long as "a" is not released. God save you if you are using recursively the instantiation of class B.

Hence by using delegate, you are able to use all the desired methods of class A and keeping yourself far from this problem as well.

Comment: The problem with this response is that it doesn't address the question. You seem to be concerned with retain cycles, while the question pertains to deciding which object is most appropriately used as a delegate.